# Gradle override the default check task

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, build

I've defined my sourceSets as

```
sourceSets {
    // Configuring SourceSets for all connector source files.
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
    test {
        // integrationTests
    }
    unitTests {
        //unitTests
    }
}

test {
   // integrationTests
}

task('unitTest', type: Test) {
  //unitTests
}
```

When I kick off `./gradlew build` it's `check` task basically calls the `test` target.

Can I override the default `gradle build` tasks's 'check' mechanism to call `unitTest` here instead of `test`?

Comment: An alternative solution to the great answer by Lukas below (especially if you can't change the source sets) is to introduce your own build task that depends on exactly what you want, like `unitTest` and `assemble`. You could call it `quickBuild` or similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, please consider just using the task `test` for unit tests and using another source set for integration tests. Gradle and its plugins follow an approach called *convention over configuration* and the convention of the Java plugin is to use the task `test` for unit tests.

---

To actually answer your question, you can access and modify the dependencies of each task using [`getDependsOn()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#getDependsOn--) and [`setDependsOn​(Iterable<?>)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#setDependsOn-java.lang.Iterable-), so a simple solution to your problem could be the following code:

```
check {
    dependsOn.clear()
    dependsOn unitTest
}
```

This removes all task dependencies from the task `check` and then adds a dependency on the task `unitTest`. However, this may cause new problems, because other plugins may automatically register task dependencies for `check` that will be removed, too.

An obvious improvement to the code above would be to just remove the dependency on the `test` task instead of all task dependencies. Sadly, this is not as simple as one would think. You may have noticed that the method `getDependsOn()` returns a `Set<Object>` and not a `Set<Task>`. For convenience, task dependencies may be expressed not only using tasks but also by passing other objects that will resolve to tasks later on (e.g. a string containing the name of a task). The [current version of the Java plugin](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/ff5dc12dbf8595b01d858b1cd3c0103fcc94b419/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPlugin.java#L432) uses a `Provider<Task>` to register the dependency between the task `check` and the task `test`. To just remove the dependency on the task `test`, you would need to iterate over all dependencies in `dependsOn` and find the one with the type [`Provider`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/Provider.html) that returns the task `test` via its [`get()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/Provider.html#get--) method. You could then remove that `Provider` from `dependsOn`.

As you can see, it is possible to remove task dependencies once they have been registered, but it is not that easy, so you should probably just follow the convention and use the task `test` for unit tests.

Comment: Agree with your first point @lukas-körfer & thank you for very well explained answer.